# How to join a heading and paragraph in without changing the <h> and <p> tags

Tags: html, css

i have a header and a below that i have sentence in a

tag. The below given is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The p element</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code gives gives me the below result:

```
The p element
This is a paragraph.
```

My expected result is:

```
The p element This is a paragraph.
```

i also don't want to change the `<h>` and `<p>` tags

Comment: you don`t have to change <h> or <p> but you have to put both in one <div> with css support somthing like : <html>
<body>
<div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr)); ">
<h1>The p element</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

Try applying the `display: inline` property.

EDIT

You would apply it to both elements:

```
<h1 style="display:inline">The p element</h1>
<p style="display:inline">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Or, using CSS:

```
p, h1 {
  display: inline;
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/ejpiller/pen/BaPQxaP)

Comment: apply it to what ?

Comment: @PayamB. Sorry, edited my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Adding CSS would do the magic. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.headline h1, .headline p {
    display: inline; 
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="headline">
    <h1>The p element</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```